# How do I get commented out lines from my input file over to my output file?

Tags: xslt

I have my script that is working exactly as I want to except I need it to include any files that are commented out as well. How can I get those commented out lines to translate over to my output file and remain commented out?

Here's my script:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
    xmlns:xd="http://www.oxygenxml.com/ns/doc/xsl" 
    xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:s9ml="http://www.standardnine.com/s9ml" exclude-result-prefixes="xs math xd xhtml s9ml" 
    xmlns:epub="http://www.idpf.org/2007/ops"
    version="3.0">
    
    
    <xsl:output method="xhtml"/>
    
    <xsl:param name="topicPrefix"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="/">
        
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
        
            <title><xsl:apply-templates select="//s9ml:metadata/s9ml:title"/></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/epub-spec.css" />
            
    </head>
    <body>
        
            <ol class="toc">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="//s9ml:exhibit"/>
            </ol>
        
    </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <!-- process exhibits referenced from toc.s9ml -->
    <xsl:template match="s9ml:exhibit">
        <xsl:element name="li" namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            
                <xsl:variable name="count" select="position()"/>
                <xsl:attribute name="id">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$topicPrefix"/>
                    <xsl:number format="0000" level="any"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            
            
            
            <xsl:element name="a"  namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                    <xsl:attribute name="href">
                        <xsl:value-of select="@path" />
                    </xsl:attribute>        
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="document(@path)//xhtml:title"/> 
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:element> 
    </xsl:template>   
     
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And here's my original file containing a commented out line:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<toc xmlns="http://www.standardnine.com/s9ml" data-uuid="3e08d679878f455991c95e300fafa976">
    <metadata thumbnailpath="../img/toc_thumbs/.crops/generic_cover_2a17dcb545914185af529895539678cd.jpeg">
        <remarks path="remarks.s9ml"/>
        
        <title>Barron’s Review Course Series: Let’s Review: Physics—The Physical Setting</title>
        
    </metadata>
    <spine>
      
            <chapter data-uuid="1531c029bb6b47ebdb8b19a90e888702" designation="Chapter" enumeration="Two" thumbnailpath="../img/toc_thumbs/.crops/ch02_thumb_0a35646c72de4b5998096ad12bbd9a4e.png" sandbox="false">
                <title>Motion in One Dimension</title>
                <exhibit path="chapter002/ch02_reader_01.html"/>
                <exhibit path="chapter002/ch02_reader_02.html"/>
                <exhibit path="chapter002/ch02_reader_03.html"/>
                <exhibit path="chapter002/ch02_reader_04.html"/>
                <exhibit path="chapter002/ch02_reader_05.html"/>
                <exhibit path="chapter002/ch02_reader_06.html"/>
                <exhibit path="chapter002/ch02_reader_07.html"/>
                <exhibit path="chapter002/ch02_reader_08.html"/>
                <exhibit path="chapter002/ch02_reader_09.html"/>
                <exhibit path="chapter002/output_ch02_reader_10.html"/>
                <exhibit path="chapter002/output_ch02_reader_10_answer_key.html"/>
                <exhibit path="chapter002/output_ch02_reader_10_explanations.html"/>
                <!--
                    <exhibit path="chapter002/ch02_reader_10.html"/>
                -->
            </chapter>
     
    </spine>
</toc>
```

I need to get that last line, which is commented out, to move over to my output file remain commented out in the new format. How can I achieve that?

Comment: When you say you want the commented out `exhibit` to remain commented out, do you mean you want to generate the same HTML for that `exhibit` as for all the other `exhibit` elements? And do you want that HTML to also be commented out? Can you give an example of the output you want to see?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something along the lines of:

**XSLT 3.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xpath-default-namespace="http://www.standardnine.com/s9ml"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
expand-text="yes">   
<xsl:output method="xhtml"/>

<xsl:param name="topicPrefix"/>
        
<xsl:template match="/toc">
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>{metadata/title}</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/epub-spec.css" />
        </head>
        <body>
            <ol class="toc">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="spine/chapter/(exhibit|comment())"/>
            </ol>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="exhibit">
    <li id="{$topicPrefix}{format-number(position(), '0000')}">
        <a href="{@path}"/>
    </li>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="comment()">
    <li id="{$topicPrefix}{format-number(position(), '0000')}">
        <a href="{parse-xml(.)/exhibit/@path}" xsl:xpath-default-namespace=""/>
    </li>
</xsl:template>
         
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I think the questioner wants the commented out `exhibit` to produce a `li` which is also commented out. If that's correct, this template should do the job: `<xsl:template match="comment()"><xsl:comment><xsl:apply-templates select="parse-xml(.)"/></xsl:comment></xsl:template>`

Comment: @ConalTuohy I don't see why they would want such thing.. In any case, your template would not suffice on its own, because the XML parsed out of the comment is in no-namespace.

Comment: I don't know why they'd want that either, but it's what I think they meant by their statement that they wanted the commented out part to "remain commented out".

Comment: Good catch about the namespace; they'd also need to change the template that matches `exhibit` so that it matches `exhibit | Q{}exhibit` instead. But I do think it's better (from the point of view of separation of concerns and also avoiding repetition) to parse the XML contained in the comment and apply a template to the result.

Comment: Just some background as to why I need to retain the commented out content. This is a table of content file being converted from s9ml to html. There are pages in the toc that are commented out so they don't appear in the book but will at some point need to be commented back in so those pages can be accessed. That's why I have to keep they commented as I run this conversion.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you also want to call the `document` function on those commented out exhibits, and apply templates to the result, and then wrap the result in a comment? Is there a reason you would not just ignore comments in your transformation, and then when it's time to uncomment the commented content, you'd edit the source file and run the transformation again?